# Cannot start mysql service

Tags: mysql

Whenever I run mysql service, i get following error.

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with 
error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and 
"journalctl -xe" for details.
```

When i run `systemctl status mysql.service`, I get following error -

**mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=3/NOTIMPLEMENTED**

Following are the error logs of Mysql:-

```
2019-03-17T10:08:15.143769Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2019-03-17T10:08:19.179052Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: 1048576 bytes should have been read. Only 147456 bytes read. Retrying for the remaining bytes.
2019-03-17T10:08:23.235026Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Retry attempts for reading partial data failed.
2019-03-17T10:08:23.235060Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Tried to read 1048576 bytes at offset 1048576, but was only able to read 147456
2019-03-17T10:08:23.235080Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 5 in a file operation.
2019-03-17T10:08:23.235097Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Error number 5 means 'Input/output error'
2019-03-17T10:08:23.235111Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
2019-03-17T10:08:23.235125Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: File (unknown): 'read' returned OS error 105. Cannot continue operation
2019-03-17T10:08:23.235138Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

Is this OS related issue or some Mysql file is corrupted? Can anybody please point what is the actual issue??

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it looks like HDD failure, error during disk IO.

It is time to deploy your backup of the database on second server and migrate operations there, while hardware issue is being resolved.

Comment: If that's HDD failure, how come OS is still running, and I can read and right to the disk??

Comment: @WatsMyName only part of the data file is covered by bad sectors, most of the files are fine for now. You can quickly verify using smartctl -a /dev/sda1